# pygame - How do I change a variable while it is being used?

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

I'm making a simple top-down game with moving and collision between player and walls, using pygame.

I made my code so that when `keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]` is `True` during the `pygame.key.get_pressed` at the state of the keyboard when it's called, `block_speed` changes to 5 instead of 3. So it works and when I hold SHIFT and move with WASD keys at the same time my speed becomes 5.

Now, the problem is when I let go of SHIFT while still moving, my speed doesn't change back to 3 but stays at 5. But if I stop moving, then move, `block_speed` changes back to 3 as expected. It seems as if any change to `block_speed` only happens when I stop moving then move again.

I'm guessing it only receives the new value of `block_speed` after the current copy of `block_speed` is done being used.

How do I change `block_speed` with SHIFT while this variable is being used by the program?

```
def run(self):

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer v1")

    block_speed = 3

    sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

    left_wall = Wall(0,0,10,resolution[1])
    wall_list.add(left_wall)
    sprite_list.add(left_wall)

    top_wall = Wall(10,0,resolution[0]-10,10)
    wall_list.add(top_wall)
    sprite_list.add(top_wall)

    test_wall = Wall(10,150,200,10)
    wall_list.add(test_wall)
    sprite_list.add(test_wall)

    player = Player(50,50)
    player.walls = wall_list
    sprite_list.add(player)

    while True:

        self.screen.fill(black)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False

            if keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
                block_speed = 5
            else:
                block_speed = 3

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.change_x += block_speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player.change_x += -block_speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player.change_y += -block_speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player.change_y += block_speed

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player.change_x = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player.change_y = 0


        sprite_list.update()
        sprite_list.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.update()
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that when you add block speed to `player.change_x`/`change_y`, it performs that calculation at that time. Changing the variable afterwards won't make a difference.

A simple solution for your case is to simply make the change to `block_speed` happen before you use it. If you do this, `block_speed` has the value you want when it comes to changing the other variables, giving you the result you want.

Edit: I realise there is another issue - that is, you only change the movement speed if the key is newly pressed (the event is fired), so changing block speed still won't change the speed unless a direction key is pressed. The solution is to do your calculation every time, regardless.

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        return False

    if keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
        block_speed = 5
    else:
        block_speed = 3

    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.change_x += block_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.change_x += -block_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.change_y += -block_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.change_y += block_speed

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            player.change_x = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            player.change_y = 0
```

An alternative would be to store the direction when a key is pressed, then multiply this up by the speed at the time you do the movement each frame:

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return False

        if keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
            player.block_speed = 5
        else:
            player.block_speed = 3

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.change_x += 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.change_x -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.change_y -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.change_y += 1

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.change_x = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.change_y = 0
```

And then in your position code, do `self.rect.x += self.change_x * self.block_speed` instead. This is probably a preferable solution.

Comment: unfortunately block_speed still doesn't change and I guess "waits" regardless for `player.change_x += block_speed` to finish before applying my SHIFT change

Comment: I also have a function in the gameloop that does this code `self.rect.x += self.change_x` if it helps

Comment: There must be something else going on in your code, as statements are executed in-order, so putting the block speed change above the usage of block speed will definitely mean that new value is used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into my code. My value does change to 5 when I hold shift+WASD but when I let go of shift while still moving it doesn't change back, does the order still matter at this point? I'm trying to make it work like sprinting in video games

Comment: I missed another factor in this - you only perform the calculation involving `block_speed` when a key is pressed, so even if it changes, you need to perform that calculation again to have the new value take effect. See my updated answer.

Comment: The thing to remember is that the variable doesn't continually get used by the program, rather, the value of the variable is used at the time the statement is run.

Comment: How do I do this? Do I move `player.change_x += block_speed` out of the event and put it in the game loop?

Comment: @martinpkmn See my answer, I have edited to give two ways of doing this. What you have suggested is essentially my second method, and is a good way of solving the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this when I come back.

Comment: @martinpkmn Well, you'll want to wait until you've checked it works first ;) If it does work for you, you can [accept the answer as per these instructions on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and tried using the code from the suggested answer but found it did not work for me. My sprite still moved at the base speed until a key was lifted.

Looking at this thread, I tried moving the `get_pressed()` key detection outside of the event loop, which fixed things.

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
    player.block_speed = 5
else:
    player.block_speed = 3

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        return False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            player.change_x += 1
        #etc.

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            player.change_x = 0
        #etc.
```

As in the above answer, in your position code have `self.rect.x += self.change_x * self.block_speed`.

This allowed me to get a speed boost effect when a certain key was held down and revert back to the base speed when it was not.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
running = True
while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       #K_UP mean releasing the key
       if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
           if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
              block_speed = 3
```